# HCSR04 Not working with python using standardfirmata

Tags: python

Im trying to code my HC-SR04 to python using standardfirmata

however i keep on gett (<property object at 0x03A6E5C8>,)

Does anyone know what that means and how do i solve this issue? Here is my code for referrence:

```
import pyfirmata
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

import time

import adafruit_hcsr04
# setting up Arduino port
port = 'COM3'
board = Arduino(port)
iter = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
iter.start()

trigger_pin=board.get_pin('d:5:o')
echo_pin=board.get_pin('d:6:i')

sonar = adafruit_hcsr04.HCSR04(trigger_pin,echo_pin)

while True:
    try:
        print((sonar.distance,))
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Retrying!")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: `sonar = adafruit_hcsr04.HCSR04` is just making `sonar` be another name for the `HCSR04` class.  You need to add `()` to the end of that to actually create an instance of the class (and asking for the `distance` attribute of the instance should then work correctly).

Comment: hi so i added ' () ' to the back of my code and now i am presented with this error     self._pin = Pin(pin.id)
NameError: name 'Pin' is not defined